# Get the sum of selected columns

Tags: php, html, mysql

In this sheet, I want to search for a time period and the location ad get the search result in another page.
[image]

[image]

this is the page i get after I search. (search.php)

```
<table class="table" id="keywords" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
    <tr> 
    <th><span>ID</span></th> 
    <th><span>Name</span></th>
    <th><span>Location</span></th>
    <th><span>Date</span></th>
    <th><span>Catagory</span></th>
    <th><span>Labour-Supplier</span></th> 
    <th><span>In-time</span></th>
    <th><span>Out-time</span></th>
    <th><span>Day</span></th>
    <th><span>Day Rate</span></th>
    <th><span>Salary</span></th>
    <th><span>OT-hours</span></th>
    <th><span>OT-rate</span></th>
    <th><span>OT-amount</span></th>
    <th><span>Allowance II</span></th>
    <th><span>TotalSalary</span></th>
    <th><span>Advance</span></th>
    <th><span>Salary-to-hand</span></th> 
</tr>
</thead>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_GET['go'])){
    $Location=$_POST['Location'];


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name,Location,Date,Category,LabourSupplier,Day,DayRate,Salary,OTHours,OTrate,OTAmount,Allowance2,TotalSalary,Advance,SalaryToHand FROM attendance WHERE Date BETWEEN '".$_POST["FDate"]."' AND '".$_POST["TDate"]."' AND Location LIKE '%" . $Location . "%' ORDER BY location DESC, Date DESC",$connection)
        or die("Failed to query database" . mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

                print "<tr>"; 
                print "<td >"  . $row['ID'] . "</td>"; 
                print "<td >" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
                print "<td >" . $row['Location'] . "</td>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['Date'] . "</th>";
                print "<td >" . $row['Category'] . "</td>";
                print "<td >" . $row['LabourSupplier'] . "</td>";
                print "<th >" . $row['InTime'] . "</th>";
                print "<th >" . $row['OutTime'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['Day'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['DayRate'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['Salary'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['OTHours'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['OTrate'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['OTAmount'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['Allowance2'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['TotalSalary'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['Advance'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th>" .  $row['SalaryToHand'] . "</th>"; 
                print "</tr>"; 
                }
                }

            }
                print "</table>"; 

                ?>
```

**I want to get the sum of the columns Day, Salary,OT hours, OT amount, Total Salary and Salary To Hand at the bottom of the table. Is there a possible way to do that or should i get the sums in another table.**

PS i tried to get the sum in a new table but this didn't work.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_GET['go'])){
    $Location=$_POST['Location'];


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name,Location,sum(Day),sum(Salary),sum(OTHours),sum(OTAmount),sum(TotalSalary),sum(Advance),sum(SalaryToHand) FROM attendance WHERE Date BETWEEN '".$_POST["FDate"]."' AND '".$_POST["TDate"]."' AND Location LIKE '%" . $Location . "%' ORDER BY location DESC, Date DESC",$connection)
        or die("Failed to query database" . mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

                print "<tr>"; 
                print "<td >"  . $row['ID'] . "</td>"; 
                print "<td >" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
                print "<td >" . $row['Location'] . "</td>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['Day'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['Salary'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['OTHours'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['OTAmount'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['TotalSalary'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th >" . $row['Advance'] . "</th>"; 
                print "<th>" .  $row['SalaryToHand'] . "</th>"; 
                print "</tr>"; 
                }
                }

            }
                print "</table>"; 

                ?>
```

Comment: You have to add a GROUP BY otherwise the sum-functions won't work

Comment: no it still doesn't work @centaurio

Comment: Or instead of querying the table again you can just sum your values in the first query within php: $salary+=$row['salary']; and then print this local variables

Comment: Just adding group by won't work. You have to define by which values you want to group. Try GROUP BY 1=1 (not tested)

Comment: Well, since no one's yet mentioned the elephant in the room... please stop using PHP's deprecated an insecure mysql_ API!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this SQL query :

```
// Get parameter
$fDate = $_POST["FDate"];
$tDate = $_POST["TDate"];
// Build SQL query
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT '' AS ID,
           '' AS Name,
           '' AS Location,
           SUM(Day) AS Day, 
           SUM(Salary) AS Salary,       
           SUM(OTHours) AS OTHours,
           SUM(OTAmount) AS OTAmount, 
           SUM(TotalSalary) AS TotalSalary,
           SUM(Advance) as Advance,
           SUM(SalaryToHand) as SalaryToHand
    FROM   attendance 
    WHERE  Date BETWEEN '{$fDate}' AND '{$tDate}' 
    AND    Location LIKE '%{$Location}%' 
    ORDER BY location DESC, Date DESC
SQL;
// Excecute it
$query = mysql_query($sql ,$connection) or die("Failed to query database" . mysql_error());
// Handle result
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  ...
}
```

Keep in mind that is not safe query (don't put $_POST param directly into SQL, use prepare statement).

@ Strawberry is right, mysqli is a safer driver than mysql. Think of a migration when you have time.

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't use the exact code but got some parts from yours and put it on the query. $query = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name,Location,sum(Day) AS Day,sum(Salary) AS Salary and so on. Again thank you!

Comment: Happy and glad to helped you :-D